# arm for windows?

Tags: windows, bridge, nyx

Does arm for windows exists as binary? Or how do I compile it?

I've tried arm for linux to connect to a winbox running a bridge using arm -i $IP:$CONTROLPORT but I just get a timeout. Should this be possible?

Thanks for any aswers.

Answer (score 2):

No, [arm is not available for Windows unless you use Cygwin](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/arm#Windows) ([ticket](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/18694)).

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to connect to **remote** box - you should specify your "ControlPort with address" via `ControlListenAddress IP:port`, all the rest of setup like `HashedControlPassword` and `DisableDebuggerAttachment 0` are exactly the same

Comment: It worked! Now I can connect with arm. You're gold.